# How do I round a double to the thirds place?

Tags: java, double, rounding

```
double1 = .05100000000003;

double2 = .05295;
```

How do I round a decimal to three places? Respectively, I'd like the output to do this 0.051 and 0.053.

I tried Math.round(double1); but I got back 0.0.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated thanks.

Comment: You could multiply by 1000, round to and divide by 1000.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code in Java. The number of zeros indicates how many decimal places you would like to round to. (In this case there are 3 zeros).

```
(double)Math.round(value * 1000d) / 1000d
```

EDIT: same answer is provided in [this previous StackOverflow Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153724/how-to-round-a-number-to-n-decimal-places-in-java)

Comment: that's weird...it works on my Java compiler (returns 0.053). What Java version are you running?

Comment: my bad that's my fault it works. i forgot to apply it to my other double